# Al momento de presionar test aparece un mensaje con lo siguiente. [Mysql][ODBC5.3(a) Driver]SLL connection error: unknown error

Tags: mysql, odbc

**Al momento de presionar test aparece un mensaje con lo siguiente.**  [Mysql][ODBC5.3(a) Driver]SLL connection error: unknown error

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Al momento de presionar *test* dónde?

Comment: Hola Jose, bienvenido, ra poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!